# Threading and Message Handling in an Android Service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service, that when starting, fires up a thread which is supposed to be the "main thread" of the service. The service is bound to two other services which is part of a library that I'm using. In this thread, I want to handle messages that is sent to the service from the services it is bound to (because this is how it works with binding... right?). The binding goes well (returns true) but my problem is that I can't seem to receive any messages at all. A description of my setup follows:

The Service:

```
class MyService extends Service {
    onCreate(...) {
        myServiceApp = new MyServiceApp(this);
    }

    onStartCommand(...) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(myServiceApp);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

The Main Thread Class:

```
class MyServiceApp() {
    private Service service;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
       void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ...
       }
    };

    void run() {
        boolean as = service.bindService(new Intent(...), ..., Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
        boolean ctrl = service.bindService(new Intent(...), ..., Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE));
        Looper.prepare();
        while(true) {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, I know that to be able to declare a handler like this, I need a message loop for the thread, so I call prepare() in the run method. I also felt like I need to run through the message loop every turn in my while loop, so I added a Looper.loop() there, but that just made the application hang on that line.

So my question is, how do I solve the problem and have the messages delivered where I want? I'm aware of that my app architecture might not be optimal, so feel free to give suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: Why isn't this just one service, rather than three?

Comment: Because the other two are part of a library that I use. I don't have the source code, and on top of that it's probably meant that they should work in a distributed way.